# Specifying the string-value 'Yes' in YAML

Tags: yaml

Consider the following document:

```
foo: Yes
```

According to [the spec](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html), `Yes` should be interpreted as a `Boolean`, not as a `String`.

However, [it seems](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues/405#issuecomment-444706860) that this document yields the same interpretation:

```
foo: 'Yes'
```

If I misunderstand, and `'Yes'` (in quotes) should in fact be understood as a `String`-typed value, where in the specs can I find justification for this?

However, if I do interpret correctly, and these documents are equivalent according to spec, how can I specify a string with the value "Yes" in YAML?

Answer (score 48):

It depends ;-)

In [YAML 1.1](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html) the bool type is defined as following:

> A Boolean represents a true/false value. Booleans are formatted as English words (“true”/“false”, “yes”/“no” or “on”/“off”) for readability and may be abbreviated as a single character “y”/“n” or “Y”/“N”.

The regexp the parser should use is

```
y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO|
true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE|
on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF
```

In [YAML 1.2.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10212-boolean) the bool type is defined as following:

> Booleans: `[ true, false ]`

Assigning the value `Yes` to a key is done via quotes:

```
foo: 'Yes'
bar: "Yes"
```

Assigning a boolean and to be compatible with future versions of YAML parsers should be done with

```
foo: false
bar: true
```

Many YAML 1.2 compatible parsers still accept the 1.1 specification for booleans.

Comment: You should not trust that validator. It rejects some valid YAML and it often outputs bogus JSON (It should throw an error for things that cannot be represented in JSON, but it also barfs on things that can be represented e.g. if you use a single key-value block style mapping with an explicit key indicator)

Comment: So, with Yaml 1.1, and specifying the value `'Yes'`, including quotes (e.g. `foo: 'Yes'`) - should that be a boolean or a string?

Comment: In YAML 1.1 a `foo: 'Yes'` is a string `foo: Yes` is a boolean according to the specification. What YAML 1.1 parsers do with that is another story.

Answer (score 4):

The most recent YAML specification (you link to something replaced 9 years ago) states:

> Application specific tag resolution rules should be restricted to resolving the “?” non-specific tag, most commonly to resolving plain scalars. These may be matched against a set of regular expressions to provide automatic resolution of integers, floats, timestamps, and similar types.

A boolean is one of these "similar types". So `True` would be interpreted as a boolean and `"True"` or `'True'` (because these are not plain scalars) as strings.

In the outdated YAML 1.1 specification `Yes` and `On` (and their opposites, and all of these in all-caps, all-lowercase) were also interpreted as booleans, but this notion was dropped from the 1.2 specification.

So you want to represent the string "Yes" (without the quotes) as a value, and if you are sure your data will be read by a parser updated after 2009, then you can use a plain scalar, single quotes, double quotes or, e.g. a block style literal scalar (assuming a sequence with single key/value mappings, with key `[1, 2]`):

```
- [1, 2]: Yes
- [1, 2]: 'Yes'
- [1, 2]: "Yes"
- [1, 2]: |
    Yes
```

All but the first will also work with a parser that only supports the YAML 1.1 standard. You can of course make sure that later processing "knows" about what you expect by explicitly starting your document with the YAML directive and the end-of-directive indicator

```
%YAML 1.2
---
```