# Packer's Ansible provisioner creates a directory named for my local user

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ansible, packer

I am trying to use the Ansible provisioner in Packer to perform privileged tasks while building an Ubuntu-based AWS AMI.

The minimal example below does perform a privileged `apt update`, but it also creates the empty directory `/home/ubuntu/~myusername`, where `myusername` is my **local** username on my desktop. (Yes, the directory name contains the tilde.)

If I try adding `become_user: ubuntu` to `diagnose.yml`, the directory does not get created, but Ansible is unable to perform `apt update`.

#### stackoverflow_example.json

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami": "ami-085925f297f89fce1",
      "instance_type": "t3.micro",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "ami_name": "stackoverflow-example"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "./diagnose.yml"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### diagnose.yml

```
---

- name: Debugging user directory problem
  hosts: default
  become: true

  tasks:
    - apt:
        update_cache: yes
```

To make sure that this was not a [YAML versioning issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648244/specifying-the-string-value-yes-in-a-yaml-property), I also tried `become: yes`.

(Note: `ami-085925f297f89fce1` is the [current official AMI](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) for Ubuntu 18.04 on an EBS-backed x86 computer in the `us-east-1` region.)

This seems like a pretty basic task, and looks to me to be consistent with the example shown in the [Packer documentation for the Ansible provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html).

Obviously, I can just delete the unwanted directory or install Ansible on the AMI, run playbooks locally, then delete Ansible, but that doesn't answer the question of **why** this directory is being created.

I am running Packer 1.5.5 on MacOS 10.14.6. Is this a bug, or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Did you try with `remote_user: ubuntu` + `become: true` ?

Comment: I did try that and forgot to mention it in the question, thanks for asking. When I did that, the `/home/ubuntu/~myusername` directory did not get created, but Ansible also failed to run `apt update` because `ubuntu` is not a privileged user.

Comment: Ever figure out why this is happening?