# ConfigurationProperties reads property keys "no" or "yes" as boolean value into Map within Map<String, Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Spring Boot version: 2.6.2

So having property in `application.yml`:

```
mapping-test:
  some-mappings:
    more-mappings:
      dog: "chow-chow"
      cat: "meow-meow"
      no: "no-no"
      yes: "yes-yes"
```

and class:

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("mapping-test")
public class TestConfigurationProperties {
    private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> someMappings;
}
```

The content in someMappings will be:

[image]

The keys "no" and "yes" in map inside `someMappings` map were read as `boolean` values.
In order to read those keys properly (as yes or no) you have to wrap them in quotation marks.
I have also tried this without Lombok (just in case :D) but the result is the same.

```
mapping-test:
  some-mappings:
    more-mappings:
      dog: "chow-chow"
      cat: "meow-meow"
      "no": "no-no"
      "yes": "yes-yes"
```

[image]

Can anyone explain me whether it's bug or feature? :)

Comment: Seems to how YAML is specified, not strictly related to java, spring or lombok. At least 1.1 according to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53648244/2442804

Comment: That's answers everything, thanks alot!