# Why truthy value should be one of [false, true]?

Tags: yamllint

I am struggling with proper YAML formatting. I have my Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - dnf: name=chrony state=present
  - service: name=chronyd state=started enabled=yes
```

and have run yamllint on it

```
  3:11      warning  truthy value should be one of [false, true]  (truthy)
  6:3       error    wrong indentation: expected at least 3  (indentation)
  7:52      error    no new line character at the end of file  (new-line-at-end-of-file)
```

What does truthy value mean?

Comment: Please use a basic YAML validator, tasks is **not** a list.

Comment: And now read the fine manual: https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rules.html#module-yamllint.rules.truthy. Please note you're now asking a different question, just about a lint rule, so the title should be changed and the now-irrelevant first part removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your initial question and description, because of an syntax error and the incorrect indention. It should be

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  
  tasks:

  - name: Ensure chrony (for time synchronization) is installed.
    yum:
      name: chrony
      state: present

  - name: Ensure chrony is running
    service:  
...
```

It will also resolve the message about

> *3:11      warning  truthy value should be one of [false, true]  (truthy)*

as `become: yes` is changed to `become: true`.

For the answer to the "why" you may have a look into [specifying the string value 'yes' in a YAML property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648738/6771046).