# OpenAPI Generator converts "no" to "false"

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I created this OpenAPI YAML definition:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: NonAdult API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/components/schemas/NonAdult:
    description: 'Waiting for 3.1.0 spec to have "paths" optional.'
    get:
      tags:
        - schemas-controller
      operationId: getSchemaDefinition
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/xml':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/NonAdult'
components:
  schemas:
    NonAdult:
      type: object
      properties:
        ageRange:
          type: string
          description: The age range of the non-adult
          xml:
            name: AGE_RANGE
        no:
          type: string
          xml:
            name: NO
        basePrice:
          type: number
          format: BigDecimal
          description: The base price for the non-adults
          xml:
            name: BASE_PRICE
        tax:
          type: number
          format: BigDecimal
          description: The tax for the non-adults
          xml:
            name: TAX
      xml:
        name: NON_ADULT
...
```

I use OpenAPI Generator Maven plugin to generate a Spring server from it.

My pom build is:

```xml
<plugin>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <configuration>
              <configOptions>
                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                  @lombok.Data
                  @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                  @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                  @lombok.Builder
                </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                <additionalProperty>jackson=false</additionalProperty>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                <java8>false</java8>
                <modelPropertyNaming>original</modelPropertyNaming>
                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                <useTags>true</useTags>
                <withXml>true</withXml>
              </configOptions>
              <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
              <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
              <generateApis>false</generateApis>
              <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
              <importMappings>
              </importMappings>
              <inputSpec>NonAdult.yaml</inputSpec>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <modelPackage>com.demo.business.domains.Demo</modelPackage>
              <typeMappings/>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <id>domain-commons-classes</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
```

But when I run `mvn clean package`, I get an error about the "no" property. It was converted to `false` in the Java class like this:

```java
@JsonProperty("ageRange")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "AGE_RANGE")
  private String ageRange;

  @JsonProperty("false")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "false")
  private String false;
```

How can I fix this? I don't want to change the name of the property because I want to map the data with an XML response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some YAML parsers treat unquoted `yes`, `y`, `no`, `n`, `on`, and `off` [as boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648738/113116).

To avoid this, add quotes around `no` in your OpenAPI file:

```yaml
        'no':   # <---
          type: string
          xml:
            name: 'NO'   # <---
```

Comment: thank you! can i ask you one more question: I'm using xml:wrapped = true to wrap NonAdult within NON_ADULTS element. but it doesn't work. I use Unmarshaller to convert NonAdult -> XML string but the result i get that is array of NonAdult, not within  NON_ADULTS element

Comment: @it_ctw I assume your array schema is similar to the last example [on this page](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/)? Maybe there are some additional Jackson annotations or configs to help with the serialization, I don't know. I suggest you [ask a new question](/questions/ask).